# Why does the Kubernetes revisionHistoryLimit default to 2?

Tags: kubernetes

Kubernetes' `.spec.revisionHistoryLimit` is used in keeping track of changes to the Deployment definition. Since these definitions are small yaml files, it doesn't seem like much (given the typical conditions of a modern cloud server) to keep 100's or more of these definitions around if necessary.

According to the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#clean-up-policy), it is going to be set to 2 (instead of unlimited). Why is this?

Comment: Downvoters: I'd like to point out that, according to https://stackoverflow.com/tour, my question is about a software development tool and I don't see how any of the 4 "don'ts" apply. I've (1) tried to answer it (doc. attached), (2) not a recommendation, (3) not warranting a discussion (although one may have been held elsewhere to come to the conclusion of 2), and (4) it's not unrelated to programming.

Comment: Here's one (minor) downside of keeping hundreds around - KubeStateMetrics' memory usage went over the set Limit in the deployment definition. It tracks all K8S objects, including old replica sets so KSM's memory consumption can grow unbounded if old objects aren't cleaned up. 

https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/issues/257

Comment: According to the documentation it is now 10 by default.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping it unlimited would eventually clog up etcd and iiuc etcd isn't designed for big data usages. Also the Kubernetes control plane is syncing and downloading regularly, which means there would be much unnecessary data to process. Just imagine a service with daily deployments, which runs for over a year.

And setting this to a high-ish number like 100 seems very random to me. Why not 1000 or 9001? Besides that, I cannot imagine anyone who might want to roll back something a hundred versions.

Anyway, we are only talking about a default setting, so you can set it to a very high number, if your use case requires it.

Comment: 100 might be a lot if you're only making changes once a week, and it might be very few if you're constantly updating - perhaps every 10 minutes based on live traffic flow. In either case, I feel like even 100k shouldn't be a big deal given they are just small text files. Idk how this is implemented but even if k8s stores the entire definition (as opposed to git-style delta tracking) this is still pretty minimal. My guess is that these are read pretty sparingly and has basically no impact on etcd. Again, just taking educated guesses here. Would love explanation

Comment: @s g Does this answer your question ? 
You can mark this answer as "accepted", in order to indicate that this answer solved your problem or most thoroughly answered your question.